# How do I get IntelliJ to recognize SBT name

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have the following SBT code

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "hello"
  )
```

But when I import via IJ (new>Module from existing source)

I see this...

[image]

Of course this is a problem if I import another module the same way, say foo...

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "foo"
  )
```

It overwrites the other project in the IJ files and so I can only have 1 sbt module at a time. If I change to say...

```
lazy val hello = project in file(".")
```

Everything works great, but my infrastructure folks have pushed back saying that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

```
lazy val root = Project("foo",file("."))
```